# Windows 7 hangs when one process start consuming too much memory

Tags: windows-7, windows, process, memory-usage

My problem is following:  I am working on a data science project and have some code performing data analysis and processing. If I take too big chunk of data to process at once the process starts consuming too much memory (but not CPU) and Windows just hangs. I can't do anything besides forcing it to shut down by pressing the power button.

Is it a problem in my OS settings or this is usual behaviour?

If this is usual, is there a way to automatically kill a process that is consuming too much memory?

Comment: [Sure is](https://bitsum.com/processlasso/)

Comment: click the blue "sure is" link in my comment above.

Comment: It's usual behavior. If you're doing data analysis on big data, you should account for memory limitations when designing your analysis/code. For data sets that are too big to fit in main memory, you should look into using algorithms/programs/services that distribute the data flow to other computers or that at least approach your data in a way that can work in one node with smaller chunks rather than the whole data set. See [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) and implementations like [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html).

Comment: My program does process data chunk by chunk, but how do I know the max. allowed chunk size before running the code? Right now I use blind guess and any time my guess was wrong I have to reset the PC.

Answer (score 1):

It's usual. You can do nothing but add more memory or just don't process too big chunks of data...You can monitor it on task manager and stop it if it uses a lot of memory.

Comment: But I am playing with the chunk size, with different options. And anytime I took too much I have to turn off the PC. It makes me crazy.

Comment: Only thing you can do is to add more RAM and it won't hang your pc